# ggplot2 - Order area plot by the range of area size

Tags: r, ggplot2, area-chart

I have a question about ordering area plot with the size. I want to sort from big size to small size. Such as,

[image]

This is my code

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,aes(x = DT, y = value,group=DMG,color=DMG)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",
              se = FALSE,
              formula = 'y ~ x',
              span = 0.8) +
  stat_smooth(se=FALSE, geom="area",
              method = "lm",
              position = position_stack(reverse = T),
              span = 0.75,aes(fill=DMG))
```

With `position_stack(reverse = T)`, just one area was an missunderstanding ordering (the pink area)

This is an input data
[data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k4lWQv9seRYV-OllWIpymW0Jf-ordBIB/view?usp=sharing)

```
#str(dmg_all)
'data.frame':   1625 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ DT   : num  0 0.19 0.284 0.362 0.397 ...
 $ DMG  : Factor w/ 5 levels "AGR_DMG","LB_DMG",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value: num  0 0.0282 0.0407 0.0503 0.0533 ...

#dmg_all$DMG
Levels: AGR_DMG LB_DMG MORT_DMG ED_DMG HPP_DMG
```

[image]

Can you guide me what I can do this. Thank you so much.

Comment: It sorts by the order of the factor. So I think you need to calculate the size and set the factor order accordingly and then plot it.

Comment: Hi @DanAdams, thank you. In the past, I calculated the size of the area and then order by that. I want to ask we have another solutions or extension options to solve this case or not :))